# Serialize xml different elements to several properties in c#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have next xml:

```
<table-display-fields>
  <field name="NAME/>
  <field name="DESCRIPTION" />
</table-display-fields>
```

I deserealize that with next code:

```
[XmlArray("table-display-fields")]
[XmlArrayItem("field")]
public TableDisplayField[] TableDisplayFields;
```

Then I add new xml element to table-display-fields node:

```
<table-display-fields>
  <record-number-field name="ID" />
  <field name="NAME/>
  <field name="DESCRIPTION" />
</table-display-fields>
```

Then add next code to deserealize record-number-field:

```
[XmlArray("table-display-fields")]
[XmlArrayItem("record-number-field")]
public TableDisplayField[] RecordTableDisplayFields;

[XmlArray("table-display-fields")]
[XmlArrayItem("field")]
public TableDisplayField[] TableDisplayFields;
```

This doesn't work. How do I deserealize new xml, and save the existing property path?

Comment: This doesn't work?  What exactly happens?

Comment: I have next exception:
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'TableDisplayConfiguration'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting field 'TableDisplayFields'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The XML element 'table-display-fields' from namespace 'http://localhost/configuration/application' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove XmlArrayItem() attribute.

```
[XmlArray("table-display-fields")] 
public object[] TableDisplayItems;
```

Each object in the `TableDisplayItems` will be either a `field` or a `record-number-field`.

Of course, if you only have one single `record-number-field` on top of your array, the solution can be much nicer. Is it the case ?

Comment: Yes it is. I need separate record-number-field and field elements.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you can give a more elaborate description on your requirement and then the direction of your approach. If a normal Serializing/Deserializing is what you are looking for you can try the below solution:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Serialization01 {
    [XmlRoot( "table-display-fields" )]
    public class TableDisplayFields {
        [XmlElement( "record-number-field" )]
        public string RecordNumberField { get; set; }

        [XmlElement( "field" )]
        public List<string> FieldName { get; set; }

        public TableDisplayFields ( ) {
            FieldName = new List<string>( 5 );
        }
    }
}
```

and use the below code for writing and reading the serialized data:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System;

namespace Serialization01 {
    class Program {
        static void Main ( string [] args ) {
            // Initiate the class
            TableDisplayFields t = new TableDisplayFields( );

            t.RecordNumberField = "ID";
            t.FieldName.Add( "NAME" );
            t.FieldName.Add( "DESCRIPTION" );

            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter( Path.Combine( Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Data.xml" ) );

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer( t.GetType( ) );

            xs.Serialize( tw, t );

            tw.Flush( );
            tw.Close( );

            TextReader tr = new StreamReader( Path.Combine( Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Data.xml" ) );
            TableDisplayFields t2 = xs.Deserialize( tr ) as TableDisplayFields;

            Console.WriteLine( "RecordNumberField for t2 is {0}", t2.RecordNumberField );
            foreach ( string field in t2.FieldName ) {
                Console.WriteLine( "Found field '{0}'", field );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not that I really want to see. This is simple solution but requires refactoring of existing code.